# PHP page loading

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'am using id param from url to get specified data from database. I also have Rewrite rule in .htaccess file to let user type just number after slash. I am using localhost for now so it looks something like this:

mypage.localhost/1

The problem is when I add slash after id in url like this mypage.localhost/1/ page loads incorrectly. There is data from database but compleatly broken layout.
There is code from php and .htaccess

```
 public function show():array
    {
        $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
        $data=array();
    if($id){
        try {
            $data=$this->get($id);
        }catch (DatabaseException)
        {
            header("Location:missingID");
            throw new DatabaseException("Failed to get paste");
        }
    }else{
        header("Location:missingID");
    }
    return $data;
}

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ out.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.html?error=$1 [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

how can i fix it? Should I add something in php file or .htaccess file?

Comment: "compleatly broken layout" - please share more details about this. The code you've shared does not use any layout

Answer (score -1):

In your .htaccess file, you can add a condition to exclude requests for files that exist from the rewrite rule. This will prevent the rule from applying to requests for static files like CSS and JS files.

Here's an updated version of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# exclude requests for existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# rewrite numeric IDs to out.php
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ out.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# rewrite error pages to index.html
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.html?error=$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The code from the initial question does not use any CSS files, so what makes you think that your change resolves the given problem?

Comment: A URL that contains only digits (or letters) and no file extension is _very_ unlikely to match the name of a CSS or JS file.